# How to change style property of div dynamically

Tags: visualforce

How to change style property of div dynamically.
Example.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!data}" var="data1">
 <div style="display:none" id="art">
  <Script>                             
       cahngestyle();
  </Script>
    somecode.............
 </div>                                 
 </apex:repeat>
```

my JavaScript

```
function cahngestyle()
{
               var el = document.getElementById('art');
              el.style.display = "block"

}
```

I am using this code to dynamically change div style none to block for every loop but it is not working. while running only first time this code is working means it is changing div style to block..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the div inside `apex:repeat`, every div will have the same ID. Use an `apex:variable` as an index in your `apex:repeat` and stick the index to the ID so that you have different ID for every div while you're iterating through. Ex:

```
<apex:variable var="index" value="{!1}" />
<apex:repeat value="{!data}" var="data1">
    <div style="display:none" id="art{!index}">
    <apex:variable var="index" value="{!index + 1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Then in your Javascript code you can reference which DIV in particular you want to change the style to. Now the DIVs will have ID like `art1`, `art2` etc.

Alternatively if you want to change the styles on all the DIVs generated in your `apex:repeat` then it's best to add `class` property on the DIV and access them by `document.getElementsByClassName`, iterate through each one of the elements in the array and apply the desired styles.

Comment: Is there any way to pass div id to javaScript so that by using that id i can change style.

Comment: Of course you can by calling your method while in the loop like : `changeStyle('art{!index}')`. The eval formulas work in Javascript too

Comment: The ID is not unique within a repeat; they will have a unique number appended to the end of each id, such as :0, :1, etc. You can use these ID values to identify an individual row within a repeat.